# how to authenticate with mobile phone number

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth

Hello i have to develop an application to allow mobile phones users post feeds, accept friend.. by sms. With the Facebook OAuth it seems impossible to authenticate on user behalf using his/her phone numbber. How coul i achieve this?

Comment: It's not possible with the public Graph API to do what you want. You can contact Facebook to see if the functionality exists on their API they have for white-listed apps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with the public Graph API to do what you want. You can contact Facebook to see if the functionality exists on their API they have for white-listed apps.

This is an answer not a comment.

The answer is that it is impossible to do that with the public API.  You can check with Facebook to see if it's possible to become a partner or get your app white listed to get that functionality.

Comment: (* rubbing my eyes *) What happened here?  :P

Comment: Some admin removed my previous answer and made it a comment.  :(  I guess they're just blindly changing them from answer to a comment rather than reading the content of it to see that it is indeed an answer.

Comment: I read some article talking about USSD from mobile phones to take over this. User can send text by using uSSD based communication. Wich favebooks api is it about?

Comment: Good question, you should contact them to find out.  Let us know what you find out.  I'll be they're either a partner or they got their app white listed.  :)